# What kind of power does the new "Lucy" have?

Tags: one-piece

Are the powers demonstrated by Luffy's replacement as Lucy based on a Devil Fruit or Haki?

It might be haki because the way he blocked Jesus Burgess' attack, but he didn't say armament haki, instead used some kind of technique.

Comment: Think this question right now would mainly be speculation over real facts. Also the way you ask the question teases to use speculative ways over confirmed facts. Try to rephrase your question a bit.

Comment: Can we all agree to just stop pretending that he might be anyone but Sabo?

Comment: isn't it a discussion type question. it should be closed.

Comment: I agree with @Dimitrimx. The question itself of "What power does Lucy have?" is fine, even if it isn't currently answerable. However, the current wording seems to encourage speculation and guessing rather than fact-based answers. Voting to close for now.

Comment: well guys, I think I found an answer. One piece wiki updated info about Sabo. There it's clearly mentioned it's haki. If you have some spare time(stop wasting it on deciding whether to close the question or not) go to this link: http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Sabo and read about Sabo's abilities. Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/8450/6166

Answer (score 1):

He was just using martial arts and haki, many characters fight using haki without saying it. You can tell he's using haki as his hands turn black.

Answer (score 0):

Lucy uses haki ;since later on he acquires the mera mera no mi and according to the previous episodes one cannot have more than one devil fruit though blackbeard is an exception