# What is Sabo's Power?

Tags: one-piece

Sabo has been shown to use Dragon type attacks in the latest episodes of One Piece. But does it have something to do with the Dragon Style of fighting (from Dragon Claw on Burgees), or has he eaten Ancient Zoan Type Dragon fruit (Dragon's breath on the Colosseum's fight ring)?

Comment: As off yet it hasn't been officially confirmed that the guy we see there is sabo. It probably will turn out ot be sabo but as far as we know sabo is dead

Comment: I don't agree with the close votes on this as opinion-based. The question doesn't seem to be answerable yet, but it will probably be answerable eventually. Questions about in-universe things which are not yet answerable are allowed, see http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/303/possible-plot-related-questions-for-shows-series-that-are-ongoing-should-be-clo.

Comment: that chapter is the first time Sabo (or whoever he is) show us his power, I think they will tell us what power he has sooner or later

Comment: @LoganM Just because the question is not opinion based does not mean it is not an obvious spoiler.  Why did you revert to the the previous version?  This question contains significant recent spoilers in the text and in the title (given that we are meant to assume he is dead).

Comment: @kaine The two were unrelated. Generally, [our policy on spoilers](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/46/what-should-our-policy-be-regarding-spoilers) is that a question doesn't need spoiler blocks. Literally anything could be considered as a spoiler by someone. An answer only needs spoiler blocks if it comes after the question does chronologically. The main goal of using spoilers is to avoid spoiling the experience of people who are looking for the answer to this question, not for people who are casually browsing...

Comment: ...Spoilers of recent content in the title are something we should try to avoid if possible, but the edited title rendered the question virtually unsearchable. A good title is always more important than avoiding spoilers, especially since over 90% of our traffic comes from search engine users, who we don't have to worry about spoiling since they're searching for that answer. If you can come up with a title that is still easily searchable and avoids spoilers, then feel free to edit that in, but I couldn't think of one quickly.

Comment: I understand the spoiler problem now. Will make sure i dont do so in the future....

Comment: Very well, if that is the spoiler policy the appropriate action to avoid spoilers is to not visit the site.  Understood.

Comment: @kaine One option to avoid spoilers is to ignore tags of series that you don't want to be spoiled in. However, if you're that concerned with spoilers, then yes, you probably shouldn't casually browse this site, because you'll definitely see them with some regularity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on Manga Chapter 744:

[image: One Piece Chapter 744]

Sabo is shown to have eaten the Mera Mera No Mi, and now has the Mera Mera logia-class power that can control fire.

Thus until chapter 744, Sabo did not have devil fruit powers.

Since he is a part of the Revolutionary Army that is lead by Monkey D. Dragon, who also happens to have saved Sabo from the evils of Goa Kingdom, so Sabo could have named his attacks based on his training under Monkey D. Dragon.

As @Sp0t pointed out, Sabo has a strong haki that can be determined by the color of his body just before the attack that destroyed the arena ring in the Dressrosa arc.

[image: Arena destruction]

Comment: along with mera mera he has very strong haki - color of armament. and maybe observation as well.

Answer (score 1):

Sabo ate the Mera Mera Fruit.

Furthermore, you see his arms darken when he uses his "dragons"-style. This implies that his fighting style is based on Haki. We now could guess that he uses elements of the fishmen Kumite or something else (I have this "everything has a core, Rebecca" clause in mind).